# Finding which day is a holiday in a large dataframe - HUGE runtime

Tags: r, dataframe, runtime, apply, lapply

I have a csv file with all the holidays of a year, which is "FILE A". I also have a quite big csv file with some data in it, which has a column containing dates in POSIXlt class. The last one is "FILE B"

The question is, how can I see which dates in FILE B are holidays? Let me arrange the environment, so you can understand it:

*Suppose that the object **holidays** contains all the holidays of the year*
*and suppose that **df** is the dataframe containing a bunch of stuff. But, the columns **dates** of **df** contains the date of that event occurrence*

The way I solve the problem was using the following functions and code

```
b <- df$dates
z <- lapply(b, isHoliday)
```

isHoliday is implemented as:

```
isHoliday<- function(var){
return ( any(holidays ==  as.Date(var))  )  #remember: var is on POSIXlt
}
```

This works, if df$dates has little amount of elements. But, my df has close to 3 million rows. And, after 15 minutes, there were no return.

For that reason, I ask again

How can I see which dates are holidays?

Comment: What is the output you are looking for, are you after a logical vector of the same length as `b`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for missing that. The output I desire is a logical vector, the same length as b, so I could bind the vector as another column

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example. Here some hints for better performance: replace POSIXlt by POSIXct, use data.table and merge both data sets.

Comment: Don't use `lapply` - you want `as.Date(b) %in% holidays` essentially I think.

Comment: @thelatemail This is quite impressive. Same implementation. One takes life, and other does it in less then 3 seconds. Because that is what I was searching for, could you post it so the topic will reach a happy end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `lapply` - you essentially want:

```
as.Date(b) %in% holidays
```

While `lapply` will loop over every single value of `b` and run `as.Date` and `any` `length(b)` times, this code will run `as.Date` once, and then do all the comparisons in vectorised, compiled code using `%in%`.

Using `==` is also incorrect because the left hand side gets recycled. E.g.:

```
1:2 == c(1:2,2:1)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```